# jquery replaceWith variable returns undefined

Tags: jquery

```
var item='<input class="item" type="text" value="1"/>';
$('#div1').replaceWith(item);
var val1 = $('.item').val();
```

This returns undefined.I think it has something to do with replacing the DOM element but I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: 1. Have you verified that `#div1` exists? 2. Do you have other elements with that same class?

Comment: item is from a $.post html response.The input displays but I can't select it $('.item') is undefined as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/YMBeX/

I suspect that you have an issue somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I'm using $.post to get the input,it displays but I can't select it.$('.item') - undefined.